# Python Unique DF in loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently writing web scraping code to scrape the PGA Tour website. I have provided a sample of a loop I am using. I would like to create a unique dataframe for every iteration through j. In the end I will have several hundred dataframes. I would like the dataframes to be listed as df1, df2, df3,...

I would then like to export all of the dataframes as a csv.

Thanks!

```
for j in range(0, 500):
    for k in range(1,9):
        try:
            print(j)
            df1 = url_base_1 + str(j) + url_base_2
            df2 = make_dataframe(df1.format(year), int(k))
            print(k)
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Use dictionaries

Comment: `export all of the dataframes as a csv` As *separate* CSV files or a single CSV file? Do you need the dataframes afterwards? If not, you can  just iteratively export rather than keeping all the dataframes in memory. If you do need them later, use `list` or `dict`.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to create a new DataFrame in each loop? Can you not append records as you process them?

Comment: I would ideally like to export as separate CSV files. It would be nice to link each statistic to each athlete name, but I dont think it will work because of the various sizes. I need to create a new dataframe because each link is for different metrics, ex. driving distance, putting average and so on. The metrics are different sizes and wont really append well.

Comment: I don't see a specific Stack Overflow question here.  For the CSV work, please search for "Python CSV output"; you'll get tutorials and other materials far more complete than we can give you here.  For the multiple variables issue ... this is a frequently asked issue on SO.  You don't name 500 variables; rather, you use a sequence of some ilk, usually a `list`.  From what you describe, it looks like you can simply reuse a single variable in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to upload into csv files separately during that iteration then below code follows, If this is what your looking or else please review your question

```
for j in range(0, 500):
    for k in range(1,9):
        try:
            file_name = 'Result_'+str(i)+'_'+str(j)+'.csv'
            df1 = url_base_1 + str(j) + url_base_2
            df2 = make_dataframe(df1.format(year), int(k))
            print(k)
            df2.to_csv(file_name,encoding='utf-8', index=False)
        except:
            pass
```

The output files will be in this format `Result_0_1.csv`, `Result_0_2.csv` and so on.

Comment: Awesome thanks so much for the help! This solved my problem!

Comment: @BradKlassen Glad to know it helped you.You can upvote the answer.Cheers