# Save DF in loop as global DF in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have looked in SO for an aswer to my question and the closest answer i have got was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54425540/python-unique-df-in-loop)

i have got the below code and what is does is loops throug a list of json files, replaces '' with NaN and then it should spit out the original DF but with the NaN values added to it. this works fine if i have just one DF but when i have multiple DF to loop through i dont know how to make the loop save the current DF that i bein iterated and save it outside the loop if that makes sense?
what is happening right now is that all the operations are being processed propperly but because we are still in a loop the DFs keep on getting overwritten by the loop itself.

what i am expecting is that the codel will take the `NPSFeedback` DF, replace all the '' with NaN, save that as the new `NPSFeedback` DF and then move on to the `courses` DF and start the same process again?

below is the code that i have created.

```
list_of_df = ['NPSFeedback', 'courses','test'] 
temp = ''
for df in list_of_df:
    print(new_df)
    temp = df + '.json'
    #print(temp)
    temp = pd.read_json(temp)
    temp = temp.replace('', np.nan)
    df = temp.copy()
    del temp
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar topics, I typically do something like

```
list_of_df = ['NPSFeedback', 'courses','test'] 
dict_df = dict()

for filename in list_of_df :
    df = pd.read_json(filename + ".json")
    df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
    dict_df[filename] = df
```

... and now I can access all dataframes from outside the loop, I can merge, etc.